# Remove back button text and center title in navigation bar

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

I've removed the text for UIBarButton in AppDelegate:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(0, -1000.f) forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Which works like a charm:

[image: UINavigationBar]

As you can see, this doesn't align the navigation title at horizontal center. What is the best solution to accomplish this globally for all views.

PS: I am using Storyboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own custom titleView with a UILabel as follows:

```
UIView *titleView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,100,50)];
UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,100,50)];

titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
titleLabel.text = @"PAKKELISTE";
[titleView addSubview:titleLabel];

self.navigationItem.titleView = titleView;
```

The details of the frames, text, alignment, etc. are just an example. The main idea though is that you set a custom UIView as the navigationItem's titleView.

It could also be an issue with your back button offset. Try this approach instead for removing the "back" text (I haven't tried this before, but I'm curious if it will work).

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.title = @"";
```

Comment: Same issue with your code as well. May seem like it's the `titleView` that gets pushed, and not the actual UILabel.

Comment: I just edited my response. Try self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.title = @"" instead of your offset code. Make sure to put it in the viewDidLoad of the viewController previous to where you need it (i.e. the viewDidLoad of your INFORMASJON viewController)

Comment: Nice, that worked like a charm :) But is it possible to put the titleView code somewhere I can reuse it everywhere?

Comment: I'm not sure. Have you tried just using self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.title = @"" without the titleView code? Using the default titleView should center properly. I'm glad this helped. As always, accepting my answer and an upvote is always appreciated :)

Comment: Nice workaround. Guess there is a good solution for doing this on all view controllers, but this has to do it for now :)

Comment: Try just adding it in the rootViewController of your navigationController. It should then work for all views you push onto the stack.